# as.factor not working with INT values on R

Tags: r

Hey guys if you could please help me. I got this dataset:

```
  q1  q2   q3 m1 m2 b1 b2
A 78 150 2887  4  4  0  1
B 74 142 2904  4  4  1  1
C 79 137 1564  4  4  1  0
D 80 164 4522  2  2  0  0
E 74 173 5025  2  3  0  1
F 73 140 1971  3  3  0  1
```

I want to transform m1:b2 into factors. If I do

```
data[,4:7] <- as.factor(data[,4:7])
```

it doesn't work, the values change to char vectors. It gets messed up like this:

```
  q1  q2   q3                  m1                  m2                  b1
A 78 150 2887 c(4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3) c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) c(4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3)
B 74 142 2904 c(4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3) c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1) c(4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3)
C 79 137 1564 c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) c(4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3) c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
D 80 164 4522 c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1) c(4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3) c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
E 74 173 5025 c(4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3) c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) c(4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3)
F 73 140 1971 c(4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3) c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1) c(4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3)
                   b2
A c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
B c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
C c(4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3)
D c(4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3)
E c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
F c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

But if I use lapply it works fine. Can you explain me why? Because I've been using as.factor(d[]) in other occasions and it worked just fine with other data.frame objects. Thank you.

Comment: how did you get the correct result from `as.factor(data[])`? With only one column at a time it would probably work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the documentation for `as.factor` (by typing `?as.factor`), you'll see it says that the first argument `x` is **"a vector of data, usually taking a small number of distinct values"**. If you supply multiple columns of a data frame, they are treated as one vector. In your example, `as.factor` creates a unique factor level for each unique value in the entire vectorized, concatenation of columns 4 through 7 of your data frame above.

You should use:

```
data[4:7] <- lapply(data[4:7], as.factor)
```

or (requiring `tidyverse` packages)

```
data <- data %>% mutate_at(4:7, as.factor)
```

Both of these solutions will correctly treat each column supplied, here columns 4, 5, 6, and 7, as their own vectors, individually. Each one is converted to a factor separately, and re-assigned appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. And I apologize, I should've took some time to read the documentation! I usually do.

Comment: No problem Paulo, it is a good question (and worth wondering why `as.factor` ONLY takes vectors as inputs...)!

Comment: Now that you've mention it, I went through some of my scripts and in fact I never used it with columns before, I actually used with vectors e.g. data$var <- as.factor(data$var) . Rookie mistake. Thank you again, I hope soon I can contribute with others here the way you guys have been helping me to learn so much.